# Labeling problems with exam class usage when using multiple chapters

Tags: counters, labels, exam, answers

Using the `exam` document class I'm trying to create a questions/answers-sheet for a book. When working on the first chapter, everything worked nicely. When I came to the second chapter, I realized I would have problems with the question numbering, since there are questions with the same numbers. The specific warnings I got was:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `question@1' multiply defined.
```

The basic layout of the body of my document is as follows:

```
\section*{Chapter 1}
\setcounter{section}{1}
    \begin{questions}
        \numberwithin{question}{section}
        \setcounter{question}{0}
        \question

            \begin{solution}

            \end{solution}
    \end{questions}

\section*{Chapter 2}
\setcounter{section}{2}
    \begin{questions}
        \numberwithin{question}{section}
        \setcounter{question}{0}
        \question

            \begin{solution}

            \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
```

Compilation still works, but my editor is giving me a page full of warnings. There has to be a better more correct way, than what I'm doing right now. Could you recommend me a different way to make such a document?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Martin. Please could you provide a complete `.tex` file (starting with `\documentclass` etc) so that I can reproduce your error on my machine?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @JohnWickerson I can't upload the full document. I have made a similar document, which produces the same warning:
https://gist.github.com/MartinRogalla/5559828

Comment: @MartinRogalla we don't need a full document we just need the example in the question fixing (you only need to add three more lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source exam class would need quite a few changes to use repeated numbers as it uses the number counter internally in several places. However to help anyone else answering and to address other problems in the posted document here is a start at a solution.

You shouldn't use star form for numbered sections, and `\numberwith` should only be used once. the fact that it wasn't having an effect and you had to manually reset the question counter is related to your use of the * form. Nested counters reset when the parent counter is incremented with `\stepcounter` (or better `\refstepcounter`) setting the section counter via `\setcounter` does not do this (and also means you can not use `\label` and `\ref` to refer to the section.

**update**
Perhaps the easiest way to restart the equation numbering without breaking the rest of the features is to maintain the counter with unique numbers eg 101, 1002, in the first section and 201, 202 in the second, and then just arrange that this gets printed as 1.1,1.2,2.1,2.1 in the heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname the#1\endcsname\thesection Chapter~\fi
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \setcounter{question}{\thesection00}%
   \quad}

\renewcommand\thequestion{%
\the\numexpr(\value{question}-49)/100\relax.%
\the\numexpr\value{question}-(100*((\value{question}-49)/100))\relax}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
\fullwidth{\section{}}
        \question aaa

            \begin{solution}
xxx
            \end{solution}


\fullwidth{\section{}}

        \question bbb

            \begin{solution}
yyy
            \end{solution}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem and the answer here didn't solved it for me.

What I did was changing two lines in the `exam.cls` file, I didn't work with chapters, but for this case you can do this:

line2566

```
\edef\@queslabel{question@\arabic{question}}%
```

to

```
\edef\@queslabel{question@\arabic{chapter}@\arabic{section}@\arabic{subsection}@\arabic{question}}%
```

and

line2893

```
\edef\@partlabel{part@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}%
```

to

```
\edef\@partlabel{part@\arabic{chapter}@\arabic{section}@\arabic{subsection}@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}%
```

I only changed this two since they were the ones giving me the warnings and I don't use subparts or subsubparts. I guess if needed, those should be changed too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changing the

> `\LoadClass{article}`

to

> `\LoadClass{book}`

2. Follow  piptin,
    modify

   2.1

> `\edef\@queslabel{question@\arabic{question}}%`

to

> `\edef\@queslabel{question@\arabic{chapter}@\arabic{section}@\arabic{subsection}@\arabic{question}}%`

2.2

> ```
> \edef\@partlabel{part@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}%
> ```

to

> `\edef\@partlabel{part@\arabic{chapter}@\arabic{section}@\arabic{subsection}@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}%`

then it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please open a new question and give the link to this question. Otherwise you won't get an answer since this area is reserved for answers of this specific question.

Comment: StackExchange isn't a message board; this is the space for answers, not discussion about answers.  Another question with a link to this one is what you really need, or add a comment to the answer you're inquiring about, asking for clarification.